# Animation with images when I click on it

Tags: ios, uiimage

I would like that when I click on the image, another image appears for 1 or 2 seconds.

I have two images (UIImage), one for pressed and another for unpressed.

Is it something like this? :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2 delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    pressed.alpha = 1.0;
    unPressed.alpha = 0.0;
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    pressed.alpha = 0.0;
    unPressed.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

But with that I can't see the pressed image.

**Edit:** My problem is to asign the image to the UIImageView I think, because when I click on it appear the pressed image but then the unPressed image not appear

**I would like any similar to that:**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0 delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    pressed.alpha = 1.0;
    unPressed.alpha = 0.0;
    self.imageButton.image = pressed.image;
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    pressed.alpha = 0.0;
    unPressed.alpha = 1.0;
    self.imageButton.image = unPressed.image;
}];
```

Comment: You've set the animation duration to .2 so it wouldn't show for very long before completion.  If you want the image to appear for 2 seconds, change the animateWithDuration to 2.

Comment: After the edit: Lots of problems with that 2nd code you posted…but what are you trying to do? Just have the button image appear for 2 seconds or do you want it to fade in?

Comment: I want it to fade in for 2 seconds like a button when you click on it

Comment: I'm thinking there might be a language-related misunderstanding… When you say fade in, you want the image to start out clear and then become less clear over 2 seconds until it's showing completely?

Comment: No sorry, the button image appear for 2 seconds

Comment: OK, cool…I've made an edit

Answer (score 1):

First off, you set the animation duration to .2 so you may want to increase the duration to 1.0 or 2.0 if you in fact want it to show for 1 or 2 seconds.

Secondly, I'm assuming these images overlap one another, so when both alphas are 1, still only one of the images will be showing. Make sure `unPressed` is hidden before starting the animation; then make sure `pressed` is hidden after ending the animation.

```
unPressed.alpha = 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0 delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    pressed.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    pulsando.alpha = 0.0;
    pressed.alpha = 0.0;
    unPressed.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

(And one more question for you… You said you wanted the image to appear for 1 or 2 seconds.  Did you want the image to just appear?  Or did you want it to fade in?  Just double checking… Because if you just want it to appear, you don't need the animation block.)

Edit: (In response to your edit)

Seems as if you don't need an animation block at all and that you're just trying to have the image appear for 2 seconds.  In which case, when the button is pressed, show the image then hide the image after 2 seconds. For example:

```
- (IBAction)buttonSelected:(UIButton*)sender {
    pressed.alpha = 1.0;
    unPressed.alpha = 0.0;
    [self performSelector:@selector(hidePressedImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}

- (void)hidePressedImage {
    pressed.alpha = 0.0;
    unPressed.alpha = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: My problem is to asign the image to the UIImageView I think, because when I click on it the pressed image appear but then the unPressed image not appear.

Comment: But the unPressed image appeared originally?

Comment: If so, make sure to hide the pressed image upon completion as I wrote in my answer because if the unPressed image appeared originally, the UIImageView is properly assigned; but, after the animation the pressed image would be hiding the it.

Comment: It isn´t a button, is a UIImageView with an UIImage that when you clic do anything

Comment: Then why this line? self.imageButton.image

Comment: OK, I made the appropriate edit to do what I think you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Two images but three variables. Every time you run this function you will see the unPressed image + pressed image (and you will see the one that was added to the view at a later time, since it will be in front).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pressed image is overlapped by normal? Try following:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2 delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    pressed.alpha = 1.0;
    unPressed.alpha = 0.0;
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    pulsando.alpha = 0.0;
    unPressed.alpha = 1.0;
    pressed.alpha = 0.0;
}];
```